# Conditional mapping to new objects with a Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of objects (a List) and want to create new objects from that stream, to be inserted into a Set. However, two or more objects in the incoming List may hash to the same Key in the Set, in which case I want to append a String from the nth List object to the one already in the Set instead of creating a new one.

Something like this, but in functional form:

```
HashSet<ClassB> mySet = new HashSet<>();
for (ClassA instanceA : classAList) {
    if (mySet.contains(ClassB.key(instanceA))) { //static method call to find the key
        mySet.get(instanceA).appendFieldA(instanceA.getFieldA());
    } else {
        mySet.add(new ClassB(instanceA));
    }
}
return mySet;
```

In functional form I though of creating something like this:

```
List classAList = new ArrayList<>();
classAList.stream()
.map(instanceA -> new ClassB(instanceA))
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

But then of course that ignores the hashmap and I don't get to combine fields my multiple instances of ClassA that would all resolve to the same ClassB. I'm not sure how to put that in there. Do I need ignore the map() call and create a custom collector instead to do this job? There seems to be more than one way to do this, but I'm new to Streams.

Comment: Well, the problem with that whole idea is that if behavior is based on state (whether an conflicting-hash object is in the Set already), then you're no longer doing things functionally.

Comment: What is `mySet.get(instanceA)` supposed to mean? I think you are confusing maps and sets.  Can you paste your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s hard to understand what you actually want as your code example does not work at all. The problem is that a `Set` does not work like a `Map`, you can’t ask it for the contained equivalent object. Besides that, you are using different objects for your `contains(…)` and `get(…)` call. Also, it’s not clear what the difference between `ClassB.key(instanceA)` and `new ClassB(instanceA)` is.

Let’s try to redefine it:

Suppose we have a key type `Key` and a method `Key.key(instanceA)` to define the group candidates. Then we have a `ClassB` which is the resulting type, created via `new ClassB(instanceA)` for a single (or primary `ClassA` instance), having an `.appendFieldA(…)` method to receive a value of another `ClassA` instance when merging two group members. Then, the original (pre Java 8) code will look as follows:

```
HashMap<Key, ClassB> myMap = new HashMap<>();
for(ClassA instanceA: classAList) {
    Key key=Key.key(instanceA);
    if(myMap.containsKey(key)) {
        myMap.get(key).appendFieldA(instanceA.getFieldA());
    } else {
        myMap.put(key, new ClassB(instanceA));
    }
}
```

Then, `myMap.values()` provides you a collection of the `ClassB` instances. If it has to be a `Set`, you may create it via

```
Set<ClassB> result=new HashSet<>(myMap.values());
```

Note that this also works, when `Key` and `ClassB` are identical as it seems to be in your code, but you may ask youself, whether you really need both, the instance created via `.key(instanceA)` and the one created via `new ClassB(instanceA)`…

---

This can be simplified via the Java 8 API as:

```
for(ClassA instanceA: classAList) {
    myMap.compute(Key.key(instanceA), (k,b)-> {
        if(b==null) b=new ClassB(instanceA);
        else b.appendFieldA(instanceA.getFieldA());
        return b;
    });
}
```

or, if you want it look even more function-stylish:

```
classAList.forEach(instanceA ->
    myMap.compute(Key.key(instanceA), (k,b)-> {
        if(b==null) b=new ClassB(instanceA);
        else b.appendFieldA(instanceA.getFieldA());
        return b;
    })
);
```

---

For a stream solution, there is the problem, that a merge function will get two instances of the same type, here `ClassB`, and can’t access the `ClassA` instance via the surrounding context like we did with the `compute` solution above. For a stream solution, we need a method in `ClassB` which returns that first `ClassA` instance, which we passed to its constructor, say `getFirstInstanceA()`. Then we can use:

```
Map<Key, ClassB> myMap = classAList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Key::key, ClassB::new, (b1,b2)->{
        b1.appendFieldA(b2.getFirstInstanceA().getFieldA());
        return b1;
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly right, as was your interpretation of where my example went wrong. In my efforts to simplify the problem statement I messed up the original code example; my apologies to everyone who noticed that the original code didn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the entries into a map that maps the hashed key to the list of elements and then call map again to convert that map into the set you are after. Something like this:

```
List classAList = new ArrayList<>();
classAList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(instanceA -> ClassB.key(instanceB)))
.entrySet()
.map(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
   .map(instanceA -> new ClassB(instanceA))
   .reduce(null, (a,b) -> a.appendFieldA(b)))
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: But `appendFieldA` does not accept objects of type `ClassB`. Besides that, passing `null` as identity value to `reduce`, implies that it might (the current implementation will) attempt to invoke `appendFieldA` on that `null` reference.

Comment: Ahh yes, you are right. I didn't realize that the question was putting classb in the set but calling appendFieldA on classa. And in order for this to work, you'd need some sort of identity classa